# ¿como hacer web service post?

Tags: webservice

Para hacer un servicio web (*post*) tengo que enviar los datos que introduzca en un formulario que le mostrare enviarlo por *post* pero no se como hacerlo. Hice una idea pero no me funcionó. Gracias de antemano.

Esto es lo q tengo q enviar por post

POST (aca va una URL)

**BODY**

```
 {"client_data":{"id_doc":"",
                 "first_name":"",
                 "last_name":"",
                 "email":"",
                 "phone":""},
   "title":"PROSPECTO DE ALIADO",
   "type":"REQUEST",
   "weight":1,
   "channel":"WEB",
   "description_markdown":"",
    "time_estimate":1728000,}
```

**este es el formulario**

```
<input type="text" id="nombres" required>

<label for="apellidos">Apellidos </label>
<input type="text" id="apellidos">

<label for="cedula">Cedula / RIF*</label>
<input type="text" id="cedula" required >

<label for="telefono">Telefono / Celular</label>
<input type="text" id="telefono">

<label for="email">Correo electronico </label>
<input type="text" id="email">

<label for="descripcion">Asunto </label>
<textarea id="descripcion"></textarea>
```

Comment: ¿Lenguaje del lado del servidor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿En que lenguaje tienes desarrollado tu sistema ?
Y como observación todos tus inputs deben tener la propiedad 'name'

```
<input type="text" id="nombres" name ="nombres" required>
```

Para que el servicio interprete los valores que estás enviandoy del alguna manera deben ser iguales a los que te pide el JSON ("Body").

Para realizar APIs para que puedas consumir la información mediante POST o GET, puedes usar [SLIM Framwework](https://www.slimframework.com/)

Suponiendo que todo lo montarás en localhost con un subdirectorio "myapp" es un ejemplo de como crear un servicio en post y tu url de acceso sería el siguiente http://localhost/myapp/api/users

```
$app->post('/api/users', function ($request, $response) { //este lo defines como tu quieras
  $input = $request->getParsedBody(); 
  print_r($input); //basicamente aqui llegan todo tu post del formulario
});
```

Comment: otra duda como se que los 'name' que coloque en los input  caera con los 
   id"id_doc":"",
 "first_name":"",
"last_name":""
osea no se si me explico bien los name tienen que ser los mismo valore q se guardan dentro del json?

Comment: por cierto esta en php ..

Comment: Que tal ! normalmente eso lo puedes controlar tu, te recomendaría que lo hagas con jquery podrías reescribir el json y mandarlo por post tal como tu gustes , checa esta referencia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876061/pass-nested-object-in-jquery-ajax